# Symfony2 Form - Complex "property" option

Tags: symfony

I have the following Entities, with the main attributes:

- Location

  - id
  - name
  - address
  - type
- Station

  - location_id
  - trigram
  - altitude
- Institute

  - location_id
  - abreviation
  - departement

Station and Institute are "inheriting" from Location: any location_id of those 2 tables refers to an id in the Location table.

As you can guess, the idea is that the different types of locations share common characteristics (gathered in Location) but also have independant ones (gathered in the Station and Institute tables).

I also have a entity "Item", and an Item can be placed and move in a location, no matter if it is a Station or an Institute.

So in my "move Item" form, I need to display all the locations in a dropdown list to select the required one. For that, I use GenemuFormBundle - select2.

**My problem:** I would like to display:

- "location.name - station.trigam" if location.type is Station
- "location.name - intitute.abreviation" if location.type is Institute

I know that what is displayed in the "select" dropdown list is determined by the "property" option:

```
$builder->add('location', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'class'         => 'MyBundle:Location',
            'property'      => 'labelSelect2', 
            'query_builder' => function(LocationRepository $lr) {
                    return $lr->createQueryBuilder('l')
                              ->orderBy('l.name', 'ASC');}
        ))
```

"labelSelect2" refers to the function getLabelSelect2() of my entity Location.
But unfortunately, even though I can know the location.type, **I don't know how to access station.trigram or institute.abreviation** from the function Location::getLabelSelect2().

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: how do you handle your "inheritance"? Do you use [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) - single/multi-table? or do you handle the inheritance yourself somehow?

Comment: It is a "home-made" inheritance, I don't use the inheritance mapping as defined in your link. The only thing is that I have a One-To-One relation between Location and Station on station.location and location.id (same for institute). I didn't really look at the "real" inheritance mapping because I thought that doing that way I wouldn't be able to use Location as a regular table. I'm gonna have a look anyway, it's maybe a better way to do it in general, not only regarding this particular problem.